# CSS grid for img items works nicely but breaks when imgs get div wrappers

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This is my first time tinkering with CSS Grid. I used it to make a responsive image grid which works really nicely in a toy example. However, when I try to use the code in my actual project, everything breaks in really weird ways. The first step that breaks it is adding div wrappers to images. (I use the wrappers to provide a placeholder for images and for some additional styling).

[JSfiddle for CSS grid that works with imgs](https://jsfiddle.net/0omadfx2/4)

```
<div class="grid">
  <img class="item" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" />
  <img ...
```

[JSfiddle for CSS grid that doesn't work after adding div wrappers](https://jsfiddle.net/0omadfx2/5/)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" /></div>
  <div ...
```

I know the wrapper doesn't do anything useful in the toy example. This is a dumbed down version of my actual project where the wrapper is useful. Is it possible for me to fix the CSS Grid so that it works with the wrappers?

Comment: you have a small failure in your template. The img-element is an `empty element` so, it have no closing tag. `<img src="" />`. You can remove the `</img>`

Comment: Oh, I thought all HTML elements could be written with a closing element. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give your imgs following CSS:

```css
.grid img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

- In your first example `.item = your images` 
  There they get the width 100% which is fine.
- In your second example `.item = your div wrapper`
  That's why your images gets their normal width (in your case 200px)

With the above CSS you can prevent this.

Comment: Hmmh, looks like something in this broke the functionality of the wrapper. The main purpose of the wrapper was to provide a placeholder until the image has loaded. Now the placeholder (I think) has the appropriate width, but it has 1px height.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/h8nztdyo/1/ (I basically just broke the URLs to simulate how it looks before the images have loaded)

Comment: I cant see any placeholder. I don't understand what goes wrong and what the desired result should look

Comment: Placeholders are the gray rectangles created by `background: #EEE;`. They're supposed to have the same width and height, but instead they are collapsed so that they have 16px height even when their width is much larger. Maybe I should post a new question about this.

Comment: ah ok, now i get it. Thats a normal behavior, because  the image has in this state no sizes. You can tricks a littlebit with CSS -> https://jsfiddle.net/d94brog2/  See the pseudo ::before and the position in item and item img